# Negative constant values in Hartmann's Dispersion formula

Tags: experimental-physics, spectroscopy

[image: Atomic Spectrum of Sodium]

Can the λo values become negative or smaller value compared to standard wavelength. I'm getting the correct values even though λo is negative. I believe λo is constant, it can be any value but my professor arguing that the λo is wavelength and it should be greater than standard wavelengths.